# PHP - If no MySQL Connection then display simple message

Tags: php, mysql

How can I catch and ignore errors when connecting to a database and display a simple text message instead?

My connection looks like this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname);
```

If the connection fails I want it simply to echo "Error connecting to the database" instead of the big error box.

EDIT:

Although error_reporting(0) did work, what worked better was just putting '@' in  front of mysqli_connect:

```
$connection = @mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname);
    if (!$connection) {
        $connection_status = 'Connection to database failed';
    } else {
        $connection_status = null;
    }

?>
<?php echo $connection_status; ?>
```

Comment: What big error box...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php):

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname);
if (!$connection)
{
    error_reporting(0);
    die("Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL);
}
```

To disable "big error boxes" (I assume standart messages?), write `error_reporting(0);` above this.

Comment: the error_reporting(0); does work, but is there anyway to only use error_reporting(0) for the connection? Turn them back on afterwards?

Comment: Yes, you can do something like in my edit. If the if clause is true, then error_reporting() stays the same as default (or previously declared).

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the documentation of [`mysqli_connect`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_connect):

> ### Examples
>
> **Example #1 mysqli_connect() example**
>
> ```
> <?php
> $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
>
> if (!$link) {
>     echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
>     echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
>     echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
>     exit;
> }
>
> echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
> echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;
>
> mysqli_close($link);
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You may set your custom handler for errors

```
register_shutdown_function("shutdownHandler");
function shutdownHandler()
{
    if (!is_null($e = error_get_last())).
    {
        echo $e['message'];
    }
}
```